# How to add images in frescoimageviewer

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to use

```
com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0
```

to show images from sdcard. Here, is the code which i am using

```
new ImageViewer.Builder<>(MyImagesActivity.this, 
                     imgs) // what is this?
                    .setStartPosition(i)
                    .show();
```

The problem is I can't figure out what is the second parameter(imgs). The doc suggests that it is a list or String[]. But I don't know what it is. Is there anyone who has used this library. Any suggestion might be highly appreciated.

Comment: imgs is the arraylist which contains the url of your images

Comment: and if i am picking from device storage, what should I do?

Comment: Then you should use image URI. Which is the path of the image inside the storage

Comment: i am using image path but it is now showing total black screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass Urls or Uris of the images as Objects[] or List.....

for Example...

```
 String[] a={"https://viralsweep.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/unsplash.jpg","http://cdn.mos.techradar.com/art/other/Beach-970-80.jpg"};

            Fresco.initialize(MainActivity.this);
            new ImageViewer.Builder(MainActivity.this, a).setStartPosition(position).show();
```

[This](http://frescolib.org/docs/supported-uris.html) also help you

Comment: No, bro i am using sdcard images. In that case, what should I do? I already created my own imageviewer using viewpager. But for curiosity, i wanna know.

Comment: Get the uris of the images in a list and add 'file://' in the beginning of each filename.

Comment: That's it... Can you print your list.. which contains uri s

Comment: I am on my phone so i can't write the exact output but the list contain the directories in string for eg. Storage/0/my folder/*.jpg or something like that.

Comment: Just add `file://` at the beginning of every uris.

Comment: It did work bro... thanks
but btw i want to add some option button in that viewer. How can I?